# Connect to Kubernetes mongo db in different namespace

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

Can anyone point out how to connect to the mongo db instance using mongo client using either command line client or from .net core programs with connection strings?

We have created a sample cluster in digitalocean with a namespace, let's say *mongodatabase*.

We installed the mongo statefulset with 3 replicas. We are able to successfully connect with the below command
 kubectl --kubeconfig=configfile.yaml -n *mongodatabase* exec -ti mongo-0 mongo
But when we connect from a different namespace or from default namespace with the pod names in the below format, it doesn't work.

```
 kubectl --kubeconfig=configfile.yaml  exec -ti mongo-0.mongo.mongodatabase.cluster.svc.local mongo
```

where *mongo-0.mongo.mongodatabase.cluster.svc.local* is in *pod-0.service_name.namespace.cluster.svc.local* (also tried pod-0.statfulset_name.namespace.cluster.svc.local and pod-0.service_name.statefulsetname.namespace.cluster.svc.local) etc.,

Can any one help with the correct dns name/connection string to be used while connecting with mongo client in command line and also from the programs like java/.net core etc.,?

Also should we use kubernetes deployment instead of statefulsets here?

Comment: May I know why this was voted for closing?

Comment: You don't use `kubectl exec` for routine connections at all.  The hostname you have there looks plausible for an ordinary Mongo client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reference the mongo service by namespaced dns.  So if your mongo service is `mymongoapp` and it is deployed in `mymongonamespace`, you should be able to access it as `mymongoapp.mymongonamespace`.

To test, I used the `bitnami/mongodb` docker client.  As follows:

From within `mymongonamespace`, this command works

```
$ kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=mymongonamespace
$ kubectl run mongodbclient --rm --tty -i --image bitnami/mongodb --command -- mongo --host mymongoapp
```

But when I switched to namespace default it didn't work

```
$ kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=default
$ kubectl run mongodbclient --rm --tty -i --image bitnami/mongodb --command -- mongo --host mymongoapp
```

Qualifying the host with the namespace then works

```
$ kubectl run mongodbclient --rm --tty -i --image bitnami/mongodb --command -- mongo --host mymongoapp.mymongonamespace
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer @frankd . Thank you very much. I was fighting with the exec command which executes command inside the container where as I had to spawn up a client container using run. Finally the below command nailed it..

kubectl run mongodbclient --rm --tty -i --image mongo --restart=Never --command -- mongo --host mongo-0.mongo.default.svc.cluster.local

The above can access the mongo from any other namespace

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get inside mongo-0 pod

```
kubectl --kubeconfig=configfile.yaml  exec -ti mongo-0 sh
```

Comment: true, this works if the statefulset is created within the same namespace. how will I access if it is in a different namespace?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/).

You can have a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) for a [`Services`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services) or for a [`Pod`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods).

Also please have a look at this [kubernetes: Service located in another namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221483/kubernetes-service-located-in-another-namespace), as I think it will provide you with answer on how to access it from different namespace.

An example would look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: default-subdomain
spec:
  selector:
    name: busybox
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: foo # Actually, no port is needed.
    port: 1234
    targetPort: 1234
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox1
  labels:
    name: busybox
spec:
  hostname: busybox-1
  subdomain: default-subdomain
  containers:
  - image: busybox:1.28
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    name: busybox
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox2
  labels:
    name: busybox
spec:
  hostname: busybox-2
  subdomain: default-subdomain
  containers:
  - image: busybox:1.28
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    name: busybox
```

> If there exists a headless service in the same namespace as the pod and with the same name as the subdomain, the cluster’s KubeDNS Server also returns an A record for the Pod’s fully qualified hostname. For example, given a Pod with the hostname set to “`busybox-1`” and the subdomain set to “`default-subdomain`”, and a headless Service named “`default-subdomain`” in the same namespace, the pod will see its own FQDN as “`busybox-1.default-subdomain.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local`”. DNS serves an A record at that name, pointing to the Pod’s IP. Both pods “`busybox1`” and “`busybox2`” can have their distinct A records.
>
> The Endpoints object can specify the  `hostname`  for any endpoint addresses, along with its IP.
>
> **Note:**  Because A records are not created for Pod names,  `hostname`  is required for the Pod’s A record to be created. A Pod with no  `hostname`  but with  `subdomain`  will only create the A record for the headless service (`default-subdomain.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local`), pointing to the Pod’s IP address. Also, Pod needs to become ready in order to have a record unless  `publishNotReadyAddresses=True`  is set on the Service.

Answer (score 0):

Your question about Deployments vs StatefulSets should be a different question.  But the answer is that the StatefulSet is used when you want "Stable Persistent Storage" [kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/).

Also from the same page "stable is synonymous with persistence across Pod (re)scheduling".  So basically your mongo instance is backed by a PeristentVolume and you want the volume reattached after the pod is rescheduled.