# How do i provide a mysql instance hosted outside the namespace to a pod that is in the namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I need to make available a mysql database hosted in namespace A to an application that is deployed in namespace 'B'.

Thus far, I've tried a few methods, most promising of which was using a combination of Endpoint and service like so:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      targetPort: 31234
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mysql
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 12.34.567.8
    ports:
      - port: 31234
```

While one instance of a mysql container has already been spinned off in namespace 'A', and exposed at 31234 via NodePort configuration.

The Application has an init container, init-mysql that pings the mysql instance, with host name 'mysql' and correct credentials. 
I expected the Application to start up as usual, but it was stuck in pod initializing state. 
When I tried to check the logs of the init-mysql, I got only the following:

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

The commands that are in use for the initContainer 'init-mysql' are:

```
          command:
            - sh
            - -c
            - 'mysqladmin ping -hmysql -P3306 -uusername -ppassword'
```

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221483/service-located-in-another-namespace)

I am posting the accepted answer from Paul (community wiki) for better visibility:

> I stumbled over the same issue and found a nice solution which does
>   not need any static ip configuration:
>
> You can access a service via it's [DNS name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) (as mentioned by you):
>   *servicename.namespace.svc.cluster.local*
>
> You can use that DNS name to reference it in [another namespace via a
>   local service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors):
>
> ```yaml
> kind: Service
> apiVersion: v1
> metadata:
>   name: service-y
>   namespace: namespace-a
> spec:
>   type: ExternalName
>   externalName: service-x.namespace-b.svc.cluster.local
>   ports:
>   - port: 80
> ```