# Kubernetes: How to link to internal services with different namespaces?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I am trying to link together two Kubernetes Services located in different namespaces like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221483/service-located-in-another-namespace). Linking them over DNS, with type ExternalName.

In namespace called "db" I wish to have a Deployment with a database. To be able to have 1 database that can be shared by different projects. To have one Persistent Volume.

But somehow it does not work like expected.

**Service inside namespace "db":**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: db-srv
  name: db-srv
  namespace: db
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "db-postgres"
    port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
  selector:
    app: db
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

**Service located in "myspace"-namespace that connects to db:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myspace-db-service
  name: myspace-db-service
  namespace: myspace
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: db-srv.db.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
  - port: 5433
    # targetPort: 5432
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

The backend attaches to myspace-service on Port 5433.

Are the ports wrong?

Comment: How does it not work as expected? What is the error? Is the db app in db namespace?

Comment: `externalName: db-srv.db.svc.cluster.local` is an oxymoron. External name should be external i.e. reachable outside of the cluster. The URL you're using is local to the cluster.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I did not get an error just a timeout error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that ports on the Service with ExternalType and the Service that it connects to need to be the same. Using targetPort on the ExternalType does not work.

**This is correct:**

> SVC(externalType) => PORT (5433) => SVC(other namespace) on PORT(5433)
>   => targetPort

**This is NOT correct:**

> SVC(externalType) => PORT (5433) => TARGETPORT (5432) => SVC(other
>   namespace) on PORT(5432) => targetPort

Comment: Moreover it looks like port in `externalName`  it's only for documentation (convention) purposes.