# Kubernetes how to pass conection string for MongoDb?

Tags: .net, mongodb, asp.net-core, kubernetes

This is my appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "PackingService": "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

This is my Deployment for app

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: test
  name: test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        io.kompose.network/dbnet: "true"
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ConnectionStrings
          value: mongodb://localhost/test
        - name: MONGO_PORT
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              key: MONGO_PORT
              name: env
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: development
        image: mlrd/smartboxes
        imagePullPolicy: ""
        name: test-api
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes: null
status: {}
```

This is my Service for Mongodb

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
  selector:
    app: mongodb
```

This doesn't work throws an error time out when I want to connect to database, what is proper way to sent connection string to application from .yaml file? Should I set aspnetcore env variable also? Should I change something in .json config file? Sorry for lack of knowledge

Comment: Where do you have your mongodb deployed ? Is it also running on the same kubernetes cluster ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case MongoDB is being created with a Deployment and you are exposing it with a Service.

In your Service, you do not declare a [Type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types). This leads me to assume you're attempting to connect to MongoDB from within Kubernetes using the ClusterIP Service type.

In your `appsettings.json` that is shown, you reference `127.0.0.1` in your connection string. As you're probably aware, this is a moniker for the [local server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) reading the file.

In your case, your client server will be separate from MongoDB. Meaning your connection attempt would not be to `127.0.0.1` but rather to the name of your Kubernetes Service resource. In this case, `mongodb`.

Here are two further points of consideration.

1) If your client server that is initiating the request is in another Kubernetes [namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/), then you will need to configure your connection string to properly [reference the FQDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221483/service-located-in-another-namespace/55650127#55650127) used on Kubernetes.

Based on your configuration above, this will probably look like: `mongodb.default.svc.cluster.local`

2) If your client server is [external to your cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/). For example, your laptop or a development server. Then you will need to modify your Service type from ClusterIP to something load a [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/). Or use an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) to expose it.

I hope this answer helps you with your issue. If you need any further clarification or information on anything feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1):

Since mongodb is deployed as a separate pod and exposed by a service you can't use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` If you have created the mongodb service in the same namespace as the app then you should use  `mongodb.svc.cluster.local`. If mongodb service is in different namespace then use `mongodb.namespacename.svc.cluster.local`