# Fluentd Kubernetes Nodejs : Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:24224

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, fluentd

**EDIT : I harcoded the fluentd service IP directly in my express app and its working.. how to get it work without harcoding ip?**

I have a couple of pods **(nodejs + express server)** running on a Kubernetes cluster.

I'd like send logs from my **nodejs pods** to a **Fluentd DeamonSet**.

But I'm getting this error :

`Fluentd error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:24224`

I'm using https://github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-node and my configuration is pretty simple:

```
const logger = require('fluent-logger')

logger.configure('pptr', {
   host: 'localhost',
   port: 24224,
   timeout: 3.0,
   reconnectInterval: 600000
});
```

My fluentd conf file:

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

# Ignore fluent logs
<label @FLUENT_LOG>
  <match fluent.*>
    @type null
  </match>
</label>

<match pptr.**>
  @type elasticsearch
  host "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST']}"
  port "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT']}"
  scheme "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME'] || 'http'}"
  ssl_verify "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFY'] || 'true'}"
  user "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER']}"
  password "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD']}"
  reload_connections "#{ENV['FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_RELOAD_CONNECTIONS'] || 'true'}"
  type_name fluentd
  logstash_format true
</match>
```

Here's the Fluentd DeamonSet config file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
    version: v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: fluentd-logging
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: fluentd-logging
        version: v1
    spec:
      serviceAccount: fluentd
      serviceAccountName: fluentd
      tolerations:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
        - name: fluentd
          image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1-debian-elasticsearch
          ports:
            - containerPort: 24224
          env:
            - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
              value: "xxx"
            - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
              value: "xxx"
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME
              value: "https"
            # Option to configure elasticsearch plugin with self signed certs
            # ================================================================
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERIFY
              value: "true"
            # Option to configure elasticsearch plugin with tls
            # ================================================================
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_VERSION
              value: "TLSv1_2"
            # X-Pack Authentication
            # =====================
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_USER
              value: "xxx"
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
              value: "xxx"
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 200Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 200Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /fluentd/etc/kubernetes.conf
              subPath: kubernetes.conf
            - name: varlog
              mountPath: /var/log
            - name: varlibdockercontainers
              mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
              readOnly: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: fluentd-conf
        - name: varlog
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

I also tried to deploy a service and expose the **24224** port :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    app: fluentd
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "24224"
      port: 24224
      targetPort: 24224
  selector:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Finally my express app (deployment) is here:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: puppet
  labels:
    app: puppet
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: puppet
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: puppet
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: puppet
          image: myrepo/my-image
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

**EDIT : I harcoded the fluentd service IP directly in my express app and its working.. how to get it work without harcoding ip?**

Comment: Your `fluentd` Daemonset is in the `kube-system` and your `puppet` Deployment in the `default` namespace. To send the data to this Daemonset you will need to use following FQDN: `fluentd.kube-system.svc.cluster.local`. Have you tried this way?

Comment: Thanks, can I put this FQDN as an env variable in my puppet deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on below parts of the question:

> I'd like send logs from my nodejs pods to a Fluentd DeamonSet.

> EDIT : I harcoded the fluentd service IP directly in my express app and its working.. how to get it work without harcoding ip?

It looks like the communication between pods and the `fluentd` service is correct (hardcoding the IP works).  The issue here is the way they can communicate with each other.

You can communicate with service `fluentd` by its name. For example (from the inside of a pod):

- `curl fluentd:24224`

**You can communicate with services by its name (like `fluentd`) only in the same namespace.** If a service is in another namespace you would need to use it's full DNS name. It's template and example is following:

- template: `service-name.namespace.svc.cluster.local`
- example: `fluentd.kube-system.svc.cluster.local`

You can also use service of type `ExternalName` to map the full DNS name of your service to a shorter version like below:

---

Assuming that (example):

- You have created a `nginx-namespace` namespace:

  - `$ kubectl create namespace nginx-namespace`
- You have an `nginx` `Deployment` inside the `nginx-namespace` and a service associated with it:

  - `$ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx --namespace=nginx-namespace`
  - `$ kubectl expose deployment nginx --port=80 --type=ClusterIP --namespace=nginx-namespace`
- You want to communicate with `nginx` `Deployment` from another namespace (i.e. `default`)

You have an option to communicate with above pod:

- By the IP address of a `Pod`

  - `10.98.132.201`
- By a (full) DNS service name

  - `nginx.nginx-namespace.svc.cluster.local`
- By an `ExternalName` type of service that points to a a (full) DNS service name

  - `nginx-service`

The example of `ExternalName` type of service:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  namespace: default # <- the same as the pod communicating with the service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: nginx.nginx-namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

You can pass this information to the pod by either:

- Environment variable: [Kubernetes.io: Define environment variable container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/)
- ConfigMap: [Kubernetes.io: Configure pod configmap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)

---

Additional resources:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Service located in another namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44329470/12257134)*