# How to access service created in another namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I'm having issues when accessing a service present in another namespace.

I have 2 namespaces (in the same cluster) airflow-dev and dask-dev.

[image]

In dask-dev namespace, I have dask cluster(dask scheduler and workers) deployed. Also, created a service (cluster IP) to dask-scheduler pod. I'm able to access dask-scheduler pod from chrome using 'kubectl port-forward' command.

`kubectl port-forward --namespace dask-dev svc/dask-dev-scheduler 5002:80`

However, am not able to access the service (or dask-scheduler pod) from a pod (airflow-scheduler) present in airflow-dev namespace. Getting '**Host or service not found**' error when trying to access it using the below

`dask-dev-scheduler.dask-dev.svc.cluster.local:8786`

Below is the service that I have created for dask-dev-scheduler. Could you please let me know how to access the service from airflow-dev namespace.

```
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dask-dev-scheduler
  namespace: dask-dev
  labels:
    app: dask-dev
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: dask-dev-4.5.7
    component: scheduler
    heritage: Helm
    release: dask-dev
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: dask-dev
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: dask-dev
spec:
  ports:
    - name: dask-dev-scheduler
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8786
      targetPort: 8786
    - name: dask-dev-webui
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8787
  selector:
    app: dask-dev
    component: scheduler
    release: dask-dev
  clusterIP: 10.0.249.111
  type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrA7u.jpg
```

Comment: You can access the service using [servicename.namespace:PORT] i.e. dask-dev-scheduler.dask-dev:5002 Read more about it in the docs [here] (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/)

This'll work if you have DNS on the cluster, according to the doc here: "You can (and almost always should) set up a DNS service for your Kubernetes cluster using an add-on." This'll make it very easy for you.

You can also try to use the IP address of the service to test, kubectl get svc -o wide will show you the IP.

Comment: Tried this but getting the below error

OSError: Timed out trying to connect to tcp://dask-dev-scheduler.dask-dev:8786 after 10 s

Comment: Similar question already exists. See if it solves your problem. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37221483/service-located-in-another-namespace)

Answer (score 5):

You can use a local service to reference an external service (a service in a different namespace) using the service [externalName Type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#externalname).

`ExternalName` services do not have selectors, or any defined ports or endpoints, therefore, you can use an ExternalName service to direct traffic to an external service.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-b
  namespace: namespace-b
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app-b
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-b-ref
  namespace: namespace-a
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: service-b.namespace-b.svc.cluster.local
```

Any traffic in `namespace-a` that connects to `service-b-ref:<port>` will be routed to `service-b` in `namespace-b` (`service-b.namespace-b.svc.cluster.local`)
Therefore, a call to `service-b-ref:3000` will route to our service-b.

---

In your example, you'd just need to create a service in `airflow-dev` that will route traffic to the `dask-dev-scheduler` in the `dask-dev` namespace:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dask-dev-svc
  namespace: airflow-dev
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: dask-dev-scheduler.dask-dev.svc.cluster.local
```

Therefore, all `airflow-dev` resources that need to connect to the `dask-dev-scheduler` would call: `dask-dev-svc:8786`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dask-dev-scheduler
  namespace: dask-dev
spec:
  ports:
    - name: dask-dev-scheduler
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8786
      targetPort: 8786
# ...
  selector:
    app: dask-dev
```

Comment: This was incredibly helpful thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The cluster domain doesn't always have to be `cluster.local`. Try just using `dask-dev-scheduler.dask-dev.svc`. Assuming Airflow respects the ndots lookup strategy in the generated resolv.conf mounted into the pod, that should find it.

Comment: I have tried this approach as well..still getting the same issue

OSError: Timed out trying to connect to tcp://dask-dev-scheduler.dask-dev.svc:8786 after 10 s

Answer (score 0):

Are you upgrading coredns to 1.8.3? I have just faced same issue with my eks cluster after upgrading from 1.19 to 1.20.
Downgrading coredns to 1.8.0 solved the issue.