# How can I integrate Openkm with postgres in kubernetes cluster

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, openkm

Openkm configuration inside k8s cluster using postgres database server which is already inside it, in a separate pod.
please I need a help from Openkm experts please guide me.

Comment: Inside k8s cluster it works fine with default database HSQL but not building a connection with Postgres server which is inside a different namespace.

Comment: This is expected behaviour since namespaces are isolated. Reference: [Using namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/namespaces/#understanding-the-motivation-for-using-namespaces). If you need any other help, please prove yamls how you deployed it to your cluster (deployments, services at least) and community will be able to help you out

Comment: Actually you can if you specify `externalName` in you service for `postgresql` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44329470/15537201)